# TYPO3: Communicate between two plugins

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-extensions

I have made two plugins, one will call `listAction` and display a list of records and the other one will call `viewAction` to display the selected record.

How can I display a page where I have created the `show` plugin with the uid of the record I want to display?

```php
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
  'Vendor.Extension',
  'List',
  [
      \Vendor\Extension\Controller\Controller::class => 'list',
  ],
  [
      \Vendor\Extension\Controller\Controller::class => '',
  ]
);
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
  'Vendor.Extension',
  'View',
  [
      \Vendor\Extension\Controller\Controller::class => 'show',
  ],
  [
      \Vendor\Extension\Controller\Controller::class => '',
  ]
);
```

What I need to do is kind of what the extension News does but the way is done in that extension is deprecated and TYPO3 says that we have to do it using multiple plugins now.

https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.3/Deprecation-89463-SwitchableControllerActions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "communication" is not between your plugins, but via the page request. Following a "more/detail"-link in your list will reload the page with additional parameters.

Here, [`f:link.action`](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/master/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Link/Action.html) is, what you're looking for. This ViewHelper enables you to link to a specified extension (`extensionName`), plugin (`pluginName`), controller (`controller`) and action (`action`).